# How to use google fonts in sendgrid?

Tags: email, sendgrid, google-font-api, email-templates, sendgrid-templates

In sendgrid I can see the preview of the fonts in the correct way but when I send a test email, Google Fonts not working as the way it should be.
I tried several ways but non of them worked.

```
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&amps;display=swap"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

@import URL(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&amps;display=swap)

    /* inter-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/inter-v12-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(''),
       url('../fonts/inter-v12-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/inter-v12-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/inter-v12-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/inter-v12-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/inter-v12-latin-regular.svg#Inter') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: Probably not programming-related, but if it is, it needs a [mcve]. May depend on email client used.

Comment: It's not very polite deleting a question when people ask you to explain it. Perhaps they've already solved similar problems 100 times in the past and know you're looking at the wrong place. That `Union` would have problems with even 10K rows. A proper table design would work fine with even 10M rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only some email clients support web fonts. [Gmail, for example, does not](https://www.smartrmail.com/blog/email-safe-fonts-web-safe-fonts-for-email-explained/) (aside from Roboto and Open Sans).

This is a good resource on [things you need to know for embedding web fonts in emails](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/web-fonts-in-email/), and covers some quirks in clients like Outlook. But ultimately, you need to know that not all clients will support it, and you will need a backup font to fallback to.